# How to fix communications link failure of MySQL with spring boot

Tags: mysql, multithreading, spring-boot

**We are using spring boot application with future class (7 threads), At a time 20000 data are processing using threads. Everything is fine in our development server but in the production server, it's giving Mysql link failure connection problem occasionally. The only difference between the production server and development server is more CPU and memory in the production server.**
*What we are getting the exception ...*

```
2019-01-03 09:16:49.318 ERROR 13652 --- [l-1768-thread-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:524)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor76.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:364)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy191.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:1
```

Comment: Can you add more details about the error message? Are you sure both systems are equal and the same processes (backup or security scans for example) are running?

Comment: Thanks, @Jeroen Heier, I have linked the exception above, please refer.

Comment: Apparently you could not connect to your DB Instance. You need to anaylze this on Network Level

Comment: @Simonare It is working for another process after failing the previous process.